# Unity - Bullet spawns in wrong position in client

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking, shooter

I am making a multiplayer game with `prefab` shooting, but unfortunately the prefab  sometimes spawns in the wrong position when I shoot from a client. The bullet tends to spawn in a location where the player was a few miliseconds ago, making that the bullet sometimes spawns inside of the player which killing the player in the process.

For shooting, I currently have this code setup to instantiate the bullet

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        float angle = GetComponentInChildren<Weapon>().angle;
        CmdShootBullet(angle);
        rigidbody.AddForce(Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle + 180, Vector3.forward) * Vector3.right * (bulletPrefab.GetComponent<Bullet>().force / 7.5f));
    }
}

[Command]
void CmdShootBullet (float angle) {
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    Bullet bulletScript = bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>();
    bulletScript.shotBy = gameObject;
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward) * Vector3.right * bulletScript.force);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
}
```

And this is the setup for the location of the player and the gun. The top one is the player, the bottom is the gun.

[image]

My guess is that it has to do with lag, that the player position does not update soon enough, so how would I make it that the bullet spawns in the position of the player in the client rather than the position of the player in the host?

Comment: I don't think you want to do that. I think you should just fix the 'bullet kills player' problem.  you should fire the bullet from the correct position (which is the one the server thinks your player is in) otherwise a lagging player could jump out of cover, and shoot without ever being seen by their opponent.

Comment: have you tried syncing to the transform instead of the rigidbody? also increasing the network send rate will help. I would double it for player and almost max it for the faster moving objects such as a bullet.

Comment: @JeffUK Alright, but how can I get the position the server thinks the player is in?

Comment: @JustinMarkwell Doesn't seem to work. If the player is falling down and shoots bellow him, the bullet spawns inside of him

Comment: @FlorisdG isn't that firepoint.position?

Comment: Ok. I would make sure to create a empty at the point of fire and parent that to the weapon. assuming the transforms are configured in the same axis then it should be good.

Comment: @JeffUK If I shoot down, the firepoint is under the player

Comment: @JustinMarkwell the firepoint actually is a child of the weapon. The thing is, if I point downwards and my player is falling down, than the bullet spawns under the player, but the player moves downwards as well and therefore the bullet spawns either at the position of the player or even, if the player moves fast, above the player

Comment: I think what you're seeing is just how network synchronisation works.  You need to deal with the fact that lag will cause things to happen in slightly odd places from the perspective of the client.  Honestly think you just need to stop bullet damage from the players' own bullets (either temporarily or permanently)